# mysql replace is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to replace space into commas(`,`) in field value in codeigniter I make this query, I try my self best but not sure what is issue

```
    $this->db->select(" main_functional_area.functional_area_txt,main_job_role.job_role_txt,COUNT(main_job_role.job_role_txt) as f_c_jobs,
    REPLACE('main_functional_area.functional_area_txt', ' ', ',')");
    $this->db->from('main_functional_area');
    $this->db->join('employer_post_job','main_functional_area.functional_area_id=employer_post_job.post_job_f_area AND employer_post_job.admin_approval = 1');
    $this->db->join('main_job_role','main_job_role.main_job_role_id=employer_post_job.post_job_role');
    $this->db->where(array('employer_post_job.admin_approval'=>'1'));
    $this->db->group_by('main_job_role.job_role_txt');
    $this->db->order_by('f_c_jobs','DESC');
    $result=$this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: always try to print your query, echo $this->db->last_query();

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$this->db->select("main_functional_area.functional_area_txt,main_job_role.job_role_txt,COUNT(main_job_role.job_role_txt) as f_c_jobs,
REPLACE(main_functional_area.functional_area_txt, ' ', ',')");
```

Removed quotes around main_functional_area.functional_area_txt in the replace function parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The [Replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) in MySql is

```
REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str)

 Returns the string  with all occurrences of the string from_str replaced by the string to_str. REPLACE() performs a case-sensitive match when searching for from_str. 
mysql> SELECT REPLACE('www.mysql.com', 'w', 'Ww');
        -> 'WwWwWw.mysql.com'
```

you used `REPLACE('main_functional_area.functional_area_txt', ' ', ',')`
I did not able to see any space in string which you are sending as first argument to the REPLACE function. Better to put all the query in  `$Query` and do replace what exactly you want to do it will work fine.

Comment: main_functional_area.functional_area_txt if it is a string then you can replace @Ramesh has given example as **REPLACE(main_functional_area.functional_area_txt, ' ', ',')** but REPLACE Fuction takes first arugment as string in the link you can see.

Comment: main_functional_area.functional_area_txt is column name in sql table.
i want spaces in main_functional_area.functional_area_txt is converted into commas(,)

Comment: main_functional_area.functional_area_txt is column name in sql table, i want the space in the value of this column is convert into commas(,)
also using in codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

try this
    REPLACE(main_functional_area.functional_area_txt, ' ', ',') as newColoumnName

Hope this might work

Comment: display the last query and see the sql query if it as you have expected
echo $this->db->last_query();